# Setting up a Cinder project with the OpenCV Block

Tags: c++, opencv, cinder

I'm trying to use the new OpenCV Block with Cinder 0.8.2. I used TinderBox to setup the project somewhere in my user directory and have just been trying to setup a basic video capture routine. I added the OpenCv Block as a group to the project.

```
cv::Mat input( toOcv( capture.getSurface() ) )
```

When I added this code I got the following errors

```
Undefined symbols:
  "cv::fastFree(void*)", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::release()    in ColourDanceApp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I broke down the above code into

```
Surface frame; 
frame = mCap.getSurface(); 
cv::Mat matrix; 
matrix = toOcv( frame ); 
cv::Mat input( matrix );
```

And found I got this error at:

```
cv::Mat matrix; (and a whole bunch of errors)
```

Its been awhile since I've done any C++ but I'm concluding from this that its a project setup problem as the code it mostly taken from the OpenCV examples. The fact that it gets that far tells me that the Cinder path is good. Theres no help in under

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but here is the solution

http://forum.libcinder.org/topic/how-to-use-cinderblocks-in-xcode

1) Set **User Header Search Paths** to:

```
"$(CINDER_PATH)/blocks/opencv/include"
```

2) Set **Other Linker Flags** to include the .a files you want to use. For example:

```
"$(CINDER_PATH)/blocks/opencv/lib/macosx/libopencv_core.a"
```

It works with latest version of Cinder downloaded from Github.